# Why is this Firebase Function running twice?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a firebase function to generate a 4 digit code as a string. However, I can see in the Firebase dashboard this is being called twice.

I trigger the function like so;

```
const requestCode = async (uid) => {
  const ref = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "codes", uid);
  const data = {
    venue_id: venueID,
    offer_id: offerID,
    status: "pending",
    created_at: serverTimestamp(),
    code: null,
  };
  await setDoc(ref, data, { merge: true });
  listenForCode(uid);
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function generateRandomNumbers() {
  const numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
  const id = numbers.join("");
  return id;
}

exports.generateCode = functions.firestore
  .document(`codes/{uid}`)
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const prevData = change.before.data();
    const newData = change.after.data();

    const code = generateRandomNumbers();

    if (prevData.code === null) {
      return await change.after.ref.set({ code: code }, { merge: true });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
```

### GIF Illustration

[image: gif of dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this Firebase Function running twice?

With a `onWrite` event you listen **for all changes** in the Cloud Firestore document, i.e. creation, update and deletion.

And with `await change.after.ref.set({ code: code }, { merge: true });` you actually update the same document that triggered the Cloud Function, which is therefore triggered a second time.

Comment: I thought I was bypassing this with  "if (prevData.code === null)..." so when it runs the second time after i'm setting the code, it would just return?

Comment: Yes because the second time `prevData.code` is not `null`. So the CF is triggered, does nothing apart returning `null` which indicates to the CF platform that the CF execution is complete.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it's generating the code twice. I'll upload a mini-clip of the dashboard.

Comment: It is triggering the CF twice because the document is modified twice. (or created once and subsequently modified). I don't know how you triggered the CF the first time but I can tell you that the second time is because you update the `code` field.